# What is the average volume of the hippocampus?

Tags: brain

I'm trying to find any information on sizes of the hippocampus?
Ideally in the average adult male & female brain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The average values of right hippocampus were recorded as follows weight 4.11572 gm, length 6.996 cm, width 1.998,volume 13.978 and surface area11.839 cubic centimetre while left hippocampus mean values were weight 3.96458gms,length 6.995, width 1.998,volume 13.976 and surface area 11.713cc. [B. Narasinga Rao, K.R.S. Prasad Rao, R. Ramana Rao. 2012. Morphometric study of hippocampus in adult human brains. *Int J Basic Appl Med Sci* 2: 139-143.](http://www.cibtech.org/J%20MEDICAL%20SCIENCES/PUBLICATIONS/2012/JMS-02-02/27-JMS%2039%20Adult%20morphometrice.pdf)

Men and women had identical volumes of amygdala and hippocampus, as well as dorsal prefrontal cortex [Ruben C. Gur, Faith Gunning-Dixon, Warren B. Bilker, Raquel E. Gur. 2002. Sex Differences in Temporo-limbic and Frontal Brain Volumes of Healthy Adults. *Cerebral Cortex* 12: 998-1003](http://cercor.oxfordjournals.org/content/12/9/998.full)

Hippocampal volume change with age: Hippocampal volume diminished by 20% from 3,584 ± 136 mm3 at age 36 to 2,870 ± 220 mm3 at age of 85, corresponding to a volume loss of about 14.6 mm3/year ([Schuff N., et al. 1999. Age-related metabolite changes and volume loss in the hippocampus by magnetic resonance spectroscopy and imaging. *Neurobiol Aging* 20: 279–285](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2733348/)).